# Table Counting Customize LaTeX

Tags: tables

I would like to have my Table counting like

> Table P1.1
> Table P1.2
> Table P1.3

I tried with `\renewcommand{\thetable}{P1.???}`, and I do not know what to put on the question marks.

EDIT
I wrote this code

```
\setcounter{figure}{0}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
\includegraphics[scale=0.5]{Figures/P1.1.png}
\caption{\label{fig:P1.1}When reading from a scale, make sure that you know what each division on the scale represents.}
\end{figure}
```

and I would like that my figure/table have [image]

Figure P1.2.png instead of P1.16.2 after using this

```
\let\oldthetable\thetable
\renewcommand{\thetable}{P1.\oldthetable}
\let\oldthefigure\thefigure
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{P1.\oldthefigure}
```

Comment: Welcome to tex.se! An [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that) or some minimal code that explains your problem is always appreciated. Could you clarify what you want?

Comment: In `P1.2`, what does `P1` (or possible `P` and `1`, individually) and `2` represent?

Comment: @Werner ,,P1`` for ,,part 1``, perhaps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on what the components of your figure/table number represent what you need to do. Here are some options:

1. `P1` is just a prefix and has no connection to anything within your document.

   ```
   \let\oldthefigure\thefigure
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{P1.\oldthefigure}
   \let\oldthetable\thetable
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{P1.\oldthetable}
   ```
2. `P1` refers to `\part` one of your document, and is therefore tied to parts.

   ```
   \let\oldthefigure\thefigure
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{P\arabic{part}.\oldthefigure}
   \let\oldthetable\thetable
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{P\arabic{part}.\oldthetable}
   ```
3. In a numbering that resembles `P1.16.2`, the `16` represents either a chapter (in the `book` or `report` class, or something similar that provides `\chapter`) or a section (in `article`, or something similar that doesn't provide `\chapter`); the former is more common than the latter. For this option you'll have to allow your figure/table numbering to be continuous across these document elements (see [Continuous v. per-chapter/section numbering of figures, tables, and other document elements](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764)) in addition to updating the counter representation:

   ```
   % Continuous figure/table numbering: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/5764
   \usepackage{chngcntr}
   \counterwithout{figure}{chapter}% or \counterwithout{figure}{section}
   \counterwithout{table}{chapter}% or \counterwithout{table}{section}
   \renewcommand{\thefigure}{P1.\arabic{figure}}
   \renewcommand{\thetable}{P1.\arabic{table}}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way I can think of doing this is simply reusing whatever `\thetable` was before:

```
\documentclass{article}
\let\oldthetable\thetable
\renewcommand{\thetable}{P1.\oldthetable}
\begin{document}
    \listoftables
    \begin{table}[tp]
        Test 1\caption{Test 1}\label{tab:test1}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[tp]
        Test 2\caption{Test 2}\label{tab:test2}
    \end{table}
    \begin{table}[tp]
        Test 3\caption{Test 3}\label{tab:test3}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```