# problem with figure numbers in lyx

Tags: floats, lyx

I want my figure to have the number 1.1 ,instead I got figure 1
[image]

Comment: This is probably related to your `documentclass`. Not all of them add the `chapter` or `section` to the figure label. There is a very detailed answer here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/28334/118712 My guess is that you want to use `\usepackage{chngcntr} \counterwithin{figure}{section}`.

Comment: thank you so much

Comment: Loading `chngcntr` is not even necessary as it should be part of your latex kernel (since 2018).