# Report with 2 parts A (Chapter 1.1,1.2 etc.) + B (Chapter 1.1,1.2 etc.)

Tags: sectioning, numbering, parts

I am trying to write a report which shuld contain two parts A + B. At the moment I have this:

[image]

What i would like to have is A instead of I , and B instead of II. and also that after B the first chapter should start again with 1. etc....

```
\documentclass[11pt, ngerman]{scrreprt} 

\begin{document}                    
\begin{spacing}{1.2} 

\part{This should be A.} 
\chapter{This should be 1.}
\section{This should be 1.1} 
\chapter{This should be 2.}
\section{This should be 2.1} 
    
\part{This should be B.} 
\chapter{This should be 1.}
\section{This should be 1.1}  
\chapter{This should be 2.}
\section{This should be 2.1} 
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please show us a short compilable TeX code resulting in your issue! Then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: I just edited the post with an example

Comment: Your code does not compile without error, because of undefined environment `spacing`. It also would not show the result of the screenshot. However, IMHO you are searching something like `\renewcommand*{\thepart}{\Alph{part}}`.

Comment: @cabohah Yes. This is a part of it. This helps me changing the sytle of the part numbering. What I also like to do is now start the mubering from beginning after part B.

Comment: And `\numberwithin` for the other question.  Stack questions work best when you focus on one question per post.

Comment: @Teepeemm I would suggest `\counterwithin` or `\counterwithin*`, because these are provided by the LaTeX kernel and do not need a package.

Comment: @FitTune Second question is also a duplicate, e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28333/277964

Comment: BTW: Please don't use random tags. You neither have a problem with the table of contents nor with TeX primitives. As a new contributor you always should read the tag description before using a tag.

Comment: @cabohah Sorry, I am new and will do my best in the next time!
Also to the \counterwithin{figure}{section}  ..... what would ie be then for me? \counterwithin{chapter}{part}?

Comment: There is an explained example for numbering chapter within part in lockstep's answer to the linked question. And because it seems you don't want to change the appearance of the chapter counter you should really read that … And if you need more help, you first should edit your question and correct the example and the screenshot.

Comment: Thank you very much my friend! I got it now. Is there a way to mark both of your links as solution?